# How can I get multiple dataframes returned from a class function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop

So I have made a class that takes in a ticker symbol, and it returns a dataframe with all the price information for the dates specified. here is the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr

# class to get stock price

class GetStockInfo():

    '''
    Class to retrieve stock info and returns it as a dataframe
    '''

    def __init__(self, ticker):

        self.ticker = ticker.upper()

    def build_df(self, start_date, end_date):

        df = pd.DataFrame(pdr.DataReader(self.ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date))

        return df
```

now this works perfectly, but ideally id like to pass in a list of symbols and have it return a seperate df for each symbol. so for example,

`symbols = ['aapl','googl','msft','tsla']`

and id like it to return 4 seperate dfs, each named `aapl_df`, `msft_df` etc. is there any way to do this?

ive tried using a for loop like so

```
for i in symbols:
    stock = GetStockInfo(i)

    i_df = stock.build_df('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
```

but im not sure how to get it to return seperate dfs.

Comment: Ok so don't think of this as a how to return multiple dfs. Think of it as, how would you go about returning multiple variables? What needs to be done on the receiving end of the return?

Comment: so the `build_df` function should be coded to take a list, and have some sort of for loop to iterate through the list and return a df for every item passed in?

Comment: Should all your symbols have the same start and end date? Then you can probably create another class function like `build_multiple_dfs` and that basically can do the `for` loop and `list/dict` like shown in the answer. And then you just call this particular function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you can also do something like this:

*Edit*:

I guess you don't need to `__init__` at all

```
class GetStockInfo():

    '''
    Class to retrieve stock info and returns it as a dataframe
    '''

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    def build_df(self, stock, start_date, end_date):

        df = pd.DataFrame(pdr.DataReader(stock.upper(), 'yahoo', start_date, end_date))

        return df

    def build_multiple(self,symbols,start_dates,end_dates):
        result = {}
        for i in range(len(symbols)):
            result[symbols[i]] = self.build_df(symbols[i],start_dates[i],end_dates[i])
        return result
```

Also, I think your question more about how to access those dfs like you mentioned `aapl_df,msft_df...`?

You can just do `results['aapl']` instead of writing `aapl_df` - and so on.

Comment: this makes sense, but then wouldn't there need to be a list called `symbols` somewhere in the construction of the class?

Comment: Oh! ticker was your stock symbol, no? You can just pass it through the function - because would it not be different for each stock?

Comment: yes. so the way the original code I posted works is if for example I do the following:
`df = GetStockInfo('aapl').build_df('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')` then I would get a df for aapl with the price. but if I want to pass in a list of tickers to get a df for each ticker in that list, thats where I am lost. I get what both of the answers here are trying to do, but I dont see how to implement that in my code

Comment: So, `GetStockInfo().build_multiple(['aapl'],['2019-01-01'],['2020-01-01'])` should be the form. Btw I'm taking lists of start and end dates - if it's always gonna be the same, you just use variables instead. In variable format, it should be : `GetStockInfo().build_multiple(['aapl','msft'],'2019-01-01','2020-01-01')`

Comment: Also, just do `results['aapl']` instead of writing `aapl_df`

Comment: I see what youre saying. this worked finally thank you! just had to remove the `[i]` from the dates but it worked.
now one follow up question, how do i access each df individually? i know its in a dictionary but if i do `result['aapl']` it says result not defined

Comment: I think you got it sorted already? But, it should be `result = GetStockInfo().build_multiple(['aapl','msft'],'2019-01-01','2020-01-01'); result['aapl'].head()`

Comment: Ahh you are correct. for some reason, my kernel wasnt updating but it works now.
Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the dataframes in a list and return that. Or better yet, in a dictionary:

```py
results = {}
for i in symbols:
    stock = GetStockInfo(i)

    results[i] = stock.build_df('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
return results
```

Comment: would this need to be in the `build_df` function or outside of it?

Comment: Depends on your preference I guess.